# strtotime() is not working, can't figure out the reason

Tags: php

Ok, i'm having some issues with strtotime(), using this php class, i'll get an response like:

Apr 03 2019, 22:32:12 CEST  Died at Level 988 by a guzzlemaw.

Then, i'm using implode() to get only Apr 03 2019, 22:32:12 CEST, however when trying to strtotime($output_str), it returns nil.

Why?

```
include_once "TibiaWebAPI.class.php";

$player = new Tibia\Player("Punbelz");

if($player->getDeaths()) {
    $lastdeath = $player->getDeaths()[0];
    $output_str = implode(" ", array_splice(explode(" ",$lastdeath),0,1));
    echo strtotime($output_str);
}
```

For reference, this is [TibiaWebAPI.class](https://github.com/madsaune/TibiaWebsiteAPI/blob/master/TibiaWebAPI.class.php)

Edit:

Even using preg_match() it doesn't work.

```php
include_once "TibiaWebAPI.class.php";

$player = new Tibia\Player("Punbelz");

if($player->getDeaths()) {
    $lastdeath = $player->getDeaths()[0];
    $pattern = "/(.*?)[0-9]+[:][0-9]+[:][0-9]+/";

    if (preg_match($pattern, $lastdeath, $matches)) {
        $myDate = $matches[0];

        echo strtotime($myDate);
    }
}
```

Comment: You should get _Notice: Only variables should be passed by reference_

Comment: Yes, but I even tried to use preg_replace or preg_match, in both cases i couldn't use strtotime().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you want `array_slice`, or you get *Notice: Only variables should be passed by reference*.  Second you need to get 5 elements:

```
$output_str = implode(" ", array_slice(explode(" ", $lastdeath), 0, 5));
echo strtotime($output_str);
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/Q4eAc)

If `Died` will always separate the two then just explode on that:

```
$output_str = explode(" Died ", $lastdeath);
echo strtotime($output_str[0]);
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/IMsYg)

Comment: If i use this implode(), i'll get: Apr 03 2019, 22:32:12 CEST Died at Level 988 and not a date(), anyway, with preg_match() or preg_replace(), it's not working as well, it's something with strtotime()

Comment: Really weird, that's true, using some online IDEs will works as well, however when getting the class response, it doesn't work, this is a print_r()

Array ( [0] => Apr 03 2019, 22:32:12 CEST Died at Level 988 by a guzzlemaw. )

Comment: Then your text isn't what you think it is, do a `var_dump()` of it and view the source of the page.